# Comparing rows in two different dataframes in python 2?

Tags: python, dataframe

So I have two different dataframes; one containing players' stats from the winter 2017 season of a local municipal league and another containing player stats from the same league but for the Fall 2017 season.

What I want to do is compare each player's stats from the Winter season with the Fall season but there are a few issues:

1. Not every player played both seasons so would I have to remove them from the data frames?
2. I know how to remove duplicates but not uniques. I'm assuming that I would need to use a loop to do so?
3. I'm not sure how to reindex such a large lists/data frames - I'm assuming that I would have to in order to compare each players' stats. I'm assuming that I'd use a loop for this?

I'm quite new to python so I don't really have any code to share, so I was wondering if someone could tell me if I was on the track? And, if they are willing, provide any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please provide sample data, including expected output? In addition, share your existing code as this will help us provide appropriate responses. In particular, read **[mcve]**.

Comment: Thanks @jpp! The link made things this process more structured!  

Here are the columns and data types:
date               datetime64[ns]
 player                    object
 gender                    object
 pass                       int64
 pass to male               int64
 pass to female             int64
 goal                       int64
 assist                     int64
 2nd assist                 int64
 throw away                 int64
 drop                       int64
 D                          int64
dtype: object

For the data frames, they're pretty much the same:

Comment: TPLplayer = TPL.groupby(' player')



TPLplayeravg = TPLplayer.aggregate(np.mean)  

pd.DataFrame(TPLplayeravg)

and

TPLplayerw = TPLwinter.groupby(' player')



TPLplayeravgw = TPLplayerw.aggregate(np.mean)  

pd.DataFrame(TPLplayeravgw)

Comment: Would I cast an .iloc using a loop?